# Cannot get uncle block in my code but it exists in Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, mining, json-rpc, uncle-blocks, block-reward

I'm following this very cool article on [how to calculate rewards for a ETH miner](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-calculate-ethereum-miner-rewards) and I'm stuck on the uncle rewards.

In the example they calculate the rewards on the ETH block with id **15349734**, [click here to open the link to this block in Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/block/15349734).
In Etherscan you can see that there is only one uncle for this block with hash:
0x9c70da5c4b5be500e7732b122179a6baa85b8f092bea32cfe717d912de6bbf5a.

I also get the same uncle hash when running this code to download the block from the cloudflare endpoint (15349734 in 0x hex is: 0xEA37E6):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0xEA37E6", true],"id":1}' https://cloudflare-eth.com/
```

Then, using the uncle hash, I try to download its block using the following command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getUncleByBlockHashAndIndex", "params": ["0x9c70da5c4b5be500e7732b122179a6baa85b8f092bea32cfe717d912de6bbf5a", "0x0"], "id": 1}' https://cloudflare-eth.com
```

The problem is that the result is null, but it shouldn't because [I can see the uncle values in Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/uncle/0x9c70da5c4b5be500e7732b122179a6baa85b8f092bea32cfe717d912de6bbf5a):

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":1}
```

Am I missing something? I'm very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash parameter for `eth_getUncleByBlockHashAndIndex` should be of the *nephew* block.

Then

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getUncleByBlockHashAndIndex", "params": ["0x537ceb6998b9ec3afd9e56956efbb449f5f1bafd1e7e187feb54ebf5f1346330", "0x0"], "id": 1}' https://cloudflare-eth.com

Returns

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "baseFeePerGas": "0x3ddf41981",
        "difficulty": "0x2bd536ca1cdc8a",
        "extraData": "0x53424943727970746f2e636f6d20506f6f6c28657529",
        "gasLimit": "0x1c9c380",
        "gasUsed": "0xd9c8b1",
        "hash": "0x9c70da5c4b5be500e7732b122179a6baa85b8f092bea32cfe717d912de6bbf5a",
        "logsBloom": "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",
        "miner": "0x8b4de256180cfec54c436a470af50f9ee2813dbb",
        "mixHash": "0x9332449e0354ec80340915082b07180d89b0155d81944e8b7c8bd35cf62cbcf1",
        "nonce": "0x22324bcf1b0a13d8",
        "number": "0xea37e5",
        "parentHash": "0xde9ef69ce59a2dc9e6ac3ff86a69d3e5215c925640086193b877c2e607bce6d9",
        "receiptsRoot": "0x2e1e17cc5276be9a5ec998ad304d533affa2b0ee4648993735f355fc638e10a7",
        "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
        "size": "0x226",
        "stateRoot": "0x5ca63f7a9dfef563db5867a54c3da50be42a162a8b8b8b3fead63739a345a89d",
        "timestamp": "0x62fb0056",
        "transactionsRoot": "0xba99242cf0990646845ff0e21be49df27c0e8a7e32b0a7b250e8ef63cbc03ccb",
        "uncles": []
    },
    "id": 1
}
```